# Azure Messaging Project Guidance (Functions/API/XML Gateway)

Tags: xml, api, azure, esb

I have an XML gateway which receives and send basically orders via XML from customers and also sends orders to suppliers with acknowledgements. So I was looking at Azure and the various technologies that could be used to replace this ageing platform, with something that is newer and more flexible if a new XML format is introduced by a new partner.

The XML order comes in and we check the database to see if it already received if not and the format and basic checks are ok we respond with an acknowledgement. The XML will be stored in a directory for later processing and if the XML has embedded images these are stored also in a directory. The content XML will be processed by another process.

So i see there are Azure Functions and logic APIs etc so was wondering what would be best to replace this functionality. I appreciate it is lite on detail but did not want to go over the top and then i would do some further research and would ask some more questions and hopefully share what i plan to do.

Many thanks in Advance

Comment: What issues do you have with the current platform? Is it just that it's a risk because it's ageing? Takes a long time to accomodate changes?

Comment: The current platform was developed along time ago and not very flexible to add new integrations i believe when it was developed a number of components were used within the application such as Biztalk, K2, etc and we may move the overall source of data to SQL Server from Oracle

Comment: How is the XML sent? Is it emailed or sent via HTTP? I'm on a project now using even hubs and we are sending messages to it via HTML posts. This is then saved to file storage (but it's easy enough to save it directly to a database). All this with almost no code. I suggest you get a free Azure account and try out event hubs. It really depends how you are getting the messages right now

Comment: Its a mixture of posts and if the partner prefers webservices

Comment: Thanks Nick i will have a look at these